# Any way to set the width of the SuggestionView width in NativeScript Angular

Tags: angular, autocomplete, nativescript

I am trying to change the width of the `SuggestionView` of the `RadAutoCompleteTextView`. Since some of the options are long and at this stage I am not sure if it is possible or not. It always seems to be the same width as the actual input box. I would appreciate any suggestions. Here is the html

```
<RadAutoCompleteTextView [items]="_practicegroups" hint="All practices" 
     suggestMode="Suggest" displayMode="Plain">
     <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView  >
         <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item"  >
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical"  padding="10" >
                <Label [text]="item.text" ></Label>
            </StackLayout>
         </ng-template>
     </SuggestionView>
</RadAutoCompleteTextView>
```

Comment: You may just enable text wrap on the label, so it would show entire text in multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Manoj . I did that and it works for me for the time being. I appreciate your help.